# RMagick: Setting opacity on a png that already has transparent elements

Tags: ruby, rmagick

I need to compose images in rmagick. If I put a png that has transparent regions on another image and set the opacity of that png to 50% the parts that where transparent become white (with 50% opacity). But I want these regions to stay transparent.

Here's my code:

```
canvas = Magick::Image.new(1024,768)
canvas.opacity = Magick::MaxRGB
image = Magick::ImageList.new('/tmp/trans.png').first
image.background_color = "none"
image.opacity = Magick::MaxRGB/2
canvas.composite!(image, 50, 50, Magick::OverCompositeOp)
canvas.write('/tmp/composite.png')
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After 8 hours of Googling I came across this post which allowed me to come up with the answer.
http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=19169

```
convert FileIn.png -channel a -evaluate Multiply 0.5 +channel FileOut.png
```

-channel a forces the selection of the alpha channel
-evaluate Multiply 0.5 modifies the transparency of the image
+channel changes the selection to include all of the channels in the output

And then to merge the two transparent png's and end up with a 3rd transparent png
(Please note I'm using GraphicsMagick for this operation instead of ImageMagick)

```
gm convert FileIn1.png FileIn2.png -background transparent -mosaic FileOut.png
```